# Validations Over Checkboxes List in VisualForce Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

In Visualforce page, I am displaying the list of permissions as checkboxes.

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes layout="pageDirection" value="{!userPermission}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllPermissions}"><br /></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

Here userPermission is a String variable and AllPermissions are the list of Permission__c object. It is displaying the list of all permissions. see the screenshot below :
[image]
Now what i need to ask you is ,for example **when any user clicks on "verify invoices" then "view invoice" options should automatically selected**. how will i achieve this functionality over dynamically generated checkboxes.

**How can i get to know id of selected checkboxes on the visualforce page at run time ? and how can i apply onselect function over specific checkbox ?**

Followed the code steps :

1. Created the Developer__c field in the Permission__c Object with assigning some values to it.
2. Earlier I was adding the Id and PermissionName__c to the List but now I have added DeveloperID__c and PermissionName__c instead of ID.

   ```
   List<SelectOption> listPermission = new List<SelectOption>();
   for(Permission__c per : allPermissions) {
       listPermission.add(new SelectOption(per.DeveloperId__c,per.PermissionName__c));
   }
   return listPermission;
   ```
3. Visual Force page code is same as above written
4. After rendering this page on the browser and developer id and name looks like

[image]

**Now the problem is , how to get checkbox element in javascript so that i can apply some logic on particular permission checkbox.** and Developer id is coming into value field, i want this developer field should become in "Id" attribute.

please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since your values come from Permission__c there you might already have a name which you are displaying as label (I assume Label__c). Now you could add the a field at Permission__c called DeveloperId__c and use a short version of the label without spaces and special characters.

You can set the Id if you use an `<apex:repeat>` to generate single `<apex:selectOption>` tags. Therefore you need to query you Permission__c into a property, eg. permissions.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!permissions}" var="permission" >
     <apex:selectOption id="{!permission.DeveloperId__c}" itemValue="{!permission.Label__c}" itemLabel="{!permission.Label__c}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

But be aware that the Id in Salesforce get mangled and you will end up with strange prefixes. I prefer in most cases to use styleClass instead which is also supported by `<apex:selectOption>` http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectOption.htm

```
<apex:selectOption styleClass="{!permission.DeveloperId__c} yourRealCSSClass" itemValue="{!permission.Label__c}" itemLabel="{!permission.Label__c}" />
```

Since more than one html-class is allowed (space separated) in styleClass, you can add your "real" CSS class too (in this example yourRealCSSClass). Therefore remember not to use spaces in your DeveloperId__c!

To trigger changes and implement logic I would use jquery to trigger check/uncheck for the checkboxes http://api.jquery.com/change/

If you want to bind a handler on all boxes you can do it like

```
$( ".yourRealCSSClass" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Your logic goes here" );
});
```

Comment: When I am using <apex:selectOption> with <apex:repeat> , It gives me the compile time error.

Comment: Compilation error: Attribute styleClass for the &lt;apex:selectOption&gt; component has been deprecated in this version and cannot be used in this page in AddCustomRole at line 92 column 182

Comment: Here is my code snippet :                           <apex:repeat value="{!permissions}" var="permission" >
      <apex:selectOption styleClass="{!permission.DeveloperId__c}" itemValue="{!permission.PermissionName__c}" itemLabel="{!permission.PermissionName__c}" />
</apex:repeat>

Comment: Sorry my fault. Depreciated since v17. Then you got to go with the id tag but then your selectors become harder but jquery has "contains" selectors.

Comment: To get the styleClass back you also could use a htmt pass through attribute and use jquery addClass()

Comment: It didn't worked for me . Please tell me another way to apply script over checkboxes.

Comment: Show me what you've tried so far with 1) pass through attribute and 2) with id-tag and what errors you got in both cases. Then we can figure something out. That 3) styleClass doesnot work is clear.

Comment: Therefore please update your question with properly formatted code. Please don't provide it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

onclick="seletfuntion(this);"

seletfuntion(val) {
alert(val.value);
}

when you pass this as param in function it will give you selected checkbox value and then perform your validation .

If you have to check on submit validation that any of checkbox is selected then 
use below script 
if($(".testClass:checked").length == 0) {
alert('Please select at least one check box');
}